# Update table from multiple checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql, forms, checkbox

I want to update a table from multiple checkboxes with dynamic fields.

I built the checkboxes with the below code:

```
<div class="form-horizontal" style="margin-right: 35px; margin-left: 0px;">
<div class="form-group">
<?  $i = 0; 
    foreach ($row_specifics as $title => $value) { ?>
        <label class="control-label col-lg-2"><?= $title ?></label>
        <div class="col-lg-1" style="padding-right: 5px; padding-left: 0px;">
            <div class="make-switch switch-small" data-on="success" data-off="danger">
                <input id="<?= $title ?>" name="<?= $title ?>" type="checkbox" <?= $value=='on' ? 'checked' : ''?> />
            </div>
        </div>
    <? $i++;
        if($i % 4 == 0) { ?> 
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"> 
        <?} 
    }?>
</div>
```

So i get this as i want it. 
[image: Preview]

When i submit my form i run a function that gets all the fields from the table `specifics` and tries to update the table with the changes from the form (checkbox)

```
foreach ($row_specifics as $title => $value) {
    $valueToInsert = ( isset($_REQUEST[$title]) ) ? $value : null;

    if( $valueToInsert ) {
        $query = mysql_query("UPDATE `specifics` SET $title = '{$valueToInsert}' WHERE `car_id`= $id");
    }
}
```

- When i change the form to `POST` and i submit test changes, nothing
  happens.
- When i change the form to `GET` and i submit test changes, i get only the `on` values in URL query.

I tried to echo the `$title` and `$valueToInsert` inside `if` to check the problem (in `POST`) but i get only three values [`ABS on / ESP on / Immobilizer on`].

**REQUEST:** I want to update the table correctly, when someone change the checkbox options. This form and checkbox is at the Edit Panel of an administration page and the user edit the specifications of a record in table.

Comment: Your checkboxes don't have any `value` attributes.

Comment: You use javascript to update checkbox `checked attrib` to on . If so, it's possible over there to be the problem

Comment: @Barmar `value` is sent in the submit, not in view of the checkboxes

Comment: @CristianBitoi not using javascript. php function. Suggestions are welcome

Comment: 1. For checkbox you don't need to include value attribute
2. GET/POST, you are checking with $_REQUEST, so that should work
3. You can do like this: if(!empty($_REQUEST[$title]), then take value, otherwise another value in else

Comment: 1. Im not. 2. U can see i use `$_REQUEST` and not `$_GET/$_POST`. 3. `isset` is used

Answer (score 0):

You should check to see if all of your values are coming through as expected. Try the following code to view all of the $_REQUEST information:

```
$_REQUEST['someRequest'] = 'sweet';
$output = 'Requests:<pre>';
ob_start();
var_export($_REQUEST);
$output .= ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$output .= '</pre>';
print $output;
```

I suggest prefixing all of your form fields so you can more easily detect them in the requests. For example:

```
<input id="<?= 'chickenButter' . $title ?>" name="<?= $title ?>" type="checkbox" />
```

And then check for 'chickenButter' in the requests:

```
$_REQUEST['chickenButterCheerios'] = 'sweet';
foreach($_REQUEST as $key => $value){
    if(stristr($key,'chickenButter')){
        $output .= $value;
    }
}
print $output;//prints sweet
```

Once you get all of your expected values, be aware of how to determine and store the state of each switch. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898646/how-to-retrieve-the-checked-state-of-a-checkbox-from-a-html-form-and-store-it-in) for more.

Comment: U should try to help using the information provided. Your answer is not helpfull